# Moagrius TileView Windows Store apps alternative

Tags: windows, windows-phone, maps

There is any port of [moagrius TileView](https://github.com/moagrius/TileView) for Windows Store Apps (Windows 8.1 / windows Phone 8.1) ?

Or any control that allow to add pin on an image with scroll and zoom ?